# The images are being stored in firestore but still in the browser its showing firebase error (Unsupported field value: undefined)?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[Firebase error (unhandled rejection)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gVoX.png)

React error on the browser:

`Unhandled Rejection (FirebaseError): Function addDoc() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field username in document posts/MkHzQWzXyayty0KfQQgP)`

Most probably the problem is in this code :

````
                // complete function
                storage
                    .ref("images")
                    .child(image.name)
                    .getDownloadURL()
                    .then(url => {
                        // Post image on db
    
                        db.collection("posts").add({
                            timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                            caption: caption,
                            imageUrl: url,
                            username: username
                        });

                        setProgress(0);
                        setCaption("");
                        setImage(null);
                    });
            }
        );
    }; ```
````

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user. The Auth object is probably in an intermediate state—such as initialization- and then username is null.

Comment: code snippet plzz :)

Comment: Look at the link to the doc in my comment plzz :)

Answer (score 1):

In the error, it says your variable `username` is `undefined`. You should make sure that it has a value. Meanwhile, you can do a quick and dirty fix like this:

```
    db.collection("posts").add({
        timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        caption: caption,
        imageUrl: url,
        username: username || null,
    });
```

This code will assign null to username when the variable username is undefined.

Comment: It worked but the issue is now its not showing the username with the post.

Comment: @AbhijeetKujur Yeah, because now you are inputting null as the username when the variable `username` is undefined. As I pointed out, variable `username` is undefined, and since you have not pasted the code of where you get that variable, I don't know why it is undefined. You would have to check that yourself.